# Develop wp8 apps without buying visual studio key?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm a new developer with no budget to buy visual studio for windows phone 8 dev.

I already used the 30 day trial that they offer, do you have ideas for alternative options? specifically the following:

1. Is there an alternative program to visual basic that I could use to develop windows phone 8 apps?
2. Is there any way to extend my expried trial or receive another trial for another program?
3. I saw that visual basic ultimate 2013 offers 90 day trial, can I develop wp8 apps with it?

Comment: How about [Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs)? You can try it for free, then after 30 days you can register for a free key. *"After installation, you can try this product for up to 30 days. You must register to obtain a free product key for ongoing use after 30 days."*

Comment: Yes, as @JoachimIsaksson said .. Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone which you used is free and you can register to extend the free license product key.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson holy sh*t you're serious!? I used the trial and had no idea they offer it for free!? Will try it asap, thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson)'s comment worked for me

> How about [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs) for Windows Phone? You can try it for free, then after 30 days you can register for a free key. "After installation, you can try this product for up to 30 days. You must register to obtain a free product key for ongoing use after 30 days."